# how can display photo from database in blade laravel

Tags: laravel

I have product with multiple photo that savad in photo table with product_id.

Photo model

```
 class Photo extends Model{
protected $fillable=['product_id','filename'];
public function product(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id');}}
```

in my Product controller save product suth that:

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
     $product=product::create($request->all());
     $id=$product->id;

     foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
        $year = Carbon::now()->year;
        $month = Carbon::now()->month;
        $day = Carbon::now()->day;
        $imagePath = "/upload/images/{$year}/{$month}/{$day}";
        $filename = $photo->store( $imagePath);
        Photo::create([
            'product_id' => $id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
     }
    $request->session()->flash('success', 'محصول با موفقیت ثبت شد!');
    return redirect(route('Products.index'));
}
```

how can show all photo that related a product in blade?

Comment: Post your blade code also

Comment: It is better to add your file's path to the photo model. You have to have a column in your photos table (name it file_path) and save $imagePath as its value.